# Diffutils block UI when updating 10 to 15 items in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        final DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult =
          DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new DiffCb(oldItems, newItems));
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            applyDiffResult(newItems, diffResult);
          }
        });
      }
    }).start();
  }
```

this is how I am doing calculation and updaing my list. But when I am updating 2,3 items, it works perfect. But when I am updaing item like 20, it block the UI for alomst 10 seconds.

Comment: If you're going to use a thread like that (don't), you may as well just use the [AsyncListDiffer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/AsyncListDiffer) provided by Google.

Answer (score 0):

This is because as per Handler's [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), the task runs on whatever thread the Handler is created on. In this case, it is your UI thread.

> When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it

You need to use HandlerThread where you assign the Handler it's own worker thread for the operation.

Do this instead when initializing your Handler :

```
HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("newthread");
thread.start();
Handler handler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());
```

Also, check this [link](https://medium.com/@frank.tan/using-handlerthread-in-android-46c285936fdd) for more information and best practices on using HandlerThread.

Comment: I used this solution. It works for 20 items but not more than 20. If internet is not available and we send like 40 messages. After connected to internet and status of message are updated, UI block for 2,3 seconds. Can you help me @Azhar?

Comment: Yes. After that I also used asynctask. But still facing this issue